# Get the value of the selected field in Drupal Form API

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a custom content type called events which has a few fields defined in it.

The field name is `field_store_name`. I can get all the options from these check boxes using this code:

```
$form['field_store']['und']['#options']
```

This is how I get the option(s) that are **selected/checked**. Is this the correct way of doing this?

```
$form_state['build_info']['args']['0']->field_store['und']
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When user submits form your custom submitter could be called.
To add custom form submitter to any form you should use:

```
/* Implements hook_form_alter(). */
function moduleName_form_alter($form, $form_state) {
  // ...
  $form['#submit'][] = 'moduleName_submitterName';
  // ...
}
```

So in custom submitter you will have all submitted values under $form_state['values']:

```
function moduleName_submitterName($form, $form_state) {
  dpm($form_state['values']);
}
```

This index will apper in $form_state array only when you submit form and will contain submitted values. $form array will still contain default values shown at form before you've changed them and submitted form.

Read more:

- An example of form submitter: https://www.drupal.org/node/717740.
- hook_form_alter(): https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7

Value you need should be **$form_state['values']**['field_store]['und'][0].

Comment: I get the following error when using it that way: `Notice:  Undefined index: values`

Comment: This index will apper in $form_state array only when you submit form and will contain submitted values. $form array will still contain default values shown at form before you've changed them and submitted form. So you should use $form_state['values'] in form submitter. Here is an example of form submitter: https://www.drupal.org/node/717740. To add custom submitter use $form['#submit'][] = 'moduleName_submitterName';